# How to return message from goREST POST endpoint?

Tags: rest, go

I am using an endpoint similar to the below code

```
type TestService struct {
    gorest.RestService `root:"/test/"`
    testPost    gorest.EndPoint `method:"POST" path:"/testPost/" postdata:"map[string]string"`
}
```

I get and handle the posted data, and want to return a payload to the calling client, i.e. success/error and a message.

I cannot make out from the documentation how to achieve this, appending the `output` tag and returning anything from the function as per a GET end point fails with the following error;

> Parameter list not matching. No matching Method found for
>   EndPoint:[testPost],type:[POST] . Expecting: #func(serv
>   DocumentService) TestPost(PostData map[string]string)# with no return
>   parameters.

Is it possible to return a payload to the client? If not can I redirect to a different end point on success / failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a way in case anyone runs into a similar issue.

It seems you can write directly using an instance of the ResponseBuilder, so I create a new response builder, set the content type to json and write my response out!

```
func(serv DocumentService) TestPost(PostData map[string]string){
    fmt.Printf("%+v", PostData)
    rb := serv.ResponseBuilder()
    rb.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    rb.Write([]byte("{type:'info', msg:'Success!'}"))
}
```

Co-incidentally to provide output via a different method you use something like;

```
serv.ResponseBuilder().Created("http://localhost:8787/orders-service/items/"+string(i.Id))
```

Which I found at http://code.google.com/p/gorest/